# Placeholder Text Not Disappearing

Tags: html

I am trying to get one of those MailChimp embedded forms to work on my website (WordPress). The placeholder text for the Email field, etc. isn't disappearing like it's supposed to.

I'm using this code:

```
< input type="email" value="Email Address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus=”if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=’‘;” onblur=”if(this.value==’‘)this.value=this.defaultValue;” >
```

I tried messing around with a placeholder attribute as well, but didn't get anywhere with that either.

Suggestions? (Thank you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your the special quote characters are throwing off the Javascript parser (tested in Chrome stable on Windows).

```html
<input type="email" value="Email Address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" >
```

The proper solution here to prevent this from occurring is to use a proper Javascript IDE that will insert valid double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with spacing (before the `input` tag, and quotation marks

```
<input type="email" value="Email Address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;">
```